# ChartJS options with Chartkick

Tags: django, chart.js, chartkick

I have a chartJS chart rendered in Django with chartkick. How do I specify the options.

`{% column_chart data %}`

For example I would like to add the following:

`options: {
            layout: {
                padding: {
                  bottom: 5
                }
              }
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that the syntax is:

`{% column_chart price_data with library={"layout":{"padding":{"bottom":20}}} %}`